# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' on get_the_author_meta

Tags: php, query

```
<?php if(!empty(get_the_author_meta('facebook',$part_cur_auth_obj->ID))){?><a href="<?php echo get_the_author_meta('facebook',$part_cur_auth_obj->ID);?>"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a><?php}?>
```

I put the above code on line one (originally on line 90 something and errored there as well) and got an error in my `author.php` template on that line.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in author.php on line 1

Note: `$part_cur_auth_obj` is just my particular theme's author object.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? Is it something particular to `get_the_author_meta`? I appear to have the right amount of parens and curly braces according to my editor... so I'm not sure why the `}` is unexpected.

I know there are alternative syntax for `if/else` but I tried those too and it didn't work, so I'm not sure what is going on.

It also appears according to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812526/conditional-statements-in-php-code-between-html-code - that both syntax should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's unwrap it to more readable form:

```
<?php
    if ( ! empty( get_the_author_meta( 'facebook', $part_cur_auth_obj->ID ) ) ) {
?><a href="<?php echo get_the_author_meta('facebook', $part_cur_auth_obj->ID);?>">
    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
</a><?php}?>
```

End the last line is a problem. There are no spaces around curly bracket and it causes the error. Just change it to `<?php } ?>` and it will work fine.

So the rule is that you should put a space after `<?php` tag - it will cause problems otherwise. You can read more on this topic here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

PS. If you combine PHP and HTML, it is better to use : notation for blocks and not brackets, I guess. It's easier to keep track with all those `endif`s, `endwhile`s and so on than with a lot of `}`.

Comment: Wow thank you... I thought spaces like that were to make it more readable _for humans_ not that it would effect the parsing itself.

Comment: Also, thanks for linking to the php.net docs to explain the parsing error. Very informative!